# Tips of Crescent

Tags: astronomy, geometry

[image]

Can it be shown mathematically that the line connecting tips of crescent is parallel to the North-South line and the line gives latitude of the plane ( When the Moon is sufficiently close to the horizon, we can approximate the surface of sky as a simple plane.)

Comment: Please don't cross-post https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/48014/16685

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can it be shown mathematically that the line connecting tips of crescent is parallel to the North-South line ... ?

As the excellent answer on Astronomy SE says, the answer is "no" because the statement is not true. The plane of the solar terminator on the moon is parallel to the plane between day and night on the Earth. Because the Earth's axis is tilted at approximately 23 degrees to it orbital plane, the solar terminator plane can be up to 23 degrees either side of the North-South axis. The only points in the year when the solar terminator on the Moon (like that on the Earth) is exactly North-South are on the March and September [equinoxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equinox).